# Why don't we write $\nabla_{X}(fY) = f\nabla_{X}Y$ instead of $\nabla_{X}(fY) = f\nabla_{X}Y+ X(f)Y$ for affine connections?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

According to do Carmo, in *Riemannian Geometry* pages 49-50, he says let $\mathcal{X}(M)$ denote the set of all vector fields of class $C^{\infty}$ on $M$. Let $\mathcal{D}(M)$ denote the ring of all real-valued functions of class $C^{\infty}$ defined on $M$. An *affine connection* $\nabla$ on differential manifold $M$ is a mapping $\nabla : \mathcal{X}(M) \times \mathcal{X}(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{X}(M)$ which is denoted by $(X,Y) \xrightarrow{\nabla} \nabla_{X}Y$ and which satisfies the following properties:

1. $\nabla_{fX+gY}Z = f\nabla_{X} Z+ g\nabla_{Y}Z$
2. $\nabla_{X}(Y+Z) = \nabla_{X}Y + \nabla_{X}Z$
3. $\nabla_{X}(fY) = f\nabla_{X}Y+ X(f)Y$

in which $X,Y,Z \in \mathcal{X}(M)$ and $f,g \in \mathcal{D}(M)$.

The first property simply is linear in the first argument $X$ right? In that case, $X$ happened to be defined as $fX + gY$ So why is the second argument different? By argument, I mean if I write the covariant derivative like $\nabla (X,Y)$, I can clearly see the linearity stated in property 1. Then property 2 looks like property 1 in this regard in that it satisfies the addition property. But the multiplication part is different. Instead of yielding just $\nabla_{X}(fY) = f\nabla_{X}Y$ it yields $\nabla_{X}(fY) = f\nabla_{X}Y+ X(f)Y$.

**My Question:**

Why don't we write  $\nabla_{X}(fY) = f\nabla_{X}Y$? Why do we specify the product rule? Why is this important for affine connections?

Remark:

Consider the first property. We have $\nabla_{fX}Z=f\nabla_X Z$. That doesn't involve the product rule, does it? So why do we need it when we are applying it $\nabla_{X}(fZ)$?

Comment: If you derive a product of functions then you get $X(fg)=gX(f)+fX(g).$ Now, $\nabla_X$ is a derivation on vectors. Thus, following the analogy it is $\nabla_X(fY)=X(f)Y+f\nabla_XY.$ This is a property that a derivative must have.

Comment: Because it's sort of a directional derivative.

Comment: @mfl But consider the first argument. We have $\nabla_{fX}Z=f\nabla_X Z$. That doesn't involve the product rule, does it? So why do we need it when we are applying it $\nabla_{X}(fZ)$?

Comment: You can take the dual of the first argument to get another kind of a connection $\nabla: E\rightarrow E \times T^*(M)$, where $E$ can be a general bundle (here the tangent bundle), and you will understand why the first argument is peculiar...

Comment: @Aszune'sHeart Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Condition 1. ($\mathcal D(\mathcal M)$-linearity) implies that $\nabla_vY$ is well defined for each ($v\in T_xM$ and $Y$ vector field around $x$). This connection thing has many alternative definitions. I guess, one could have also started directly with the smooth bunge of these 'generalized directional derivatives' $\nabla_v$.

Comment: @StanShunpike: Going back to (your response to) mfl's comment, there's a big difference between $(fX)(g) = f(Xg)$ ("linearity over functions in the first argument") and $X(fg) = g(Xf) + f(Xg)$ ("Leibniz rule in the second argument"). Another way to say the same thing is, the value of a directional derivative $Xf$ at a point $p$ depends only on the value of $X$ at $p$, but it depends on $f$ is a _neighborhood_ of $p$, not just on the value $f(p)$.

Comment: @user86418 How does this distinction of point versus neighborhood answer my original question? I'm just confused so let me take a guess. So are you saying that because $X$ depends on a neighborhood of $f$ at $p$ that we then have to use the product rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\vec}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Del}{\nabla}$Let's consider the special case $M = \Reals$, on which there's a non-vanishing vector field (i.e., a global frame) $\vec = \dd/\dd x$.

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be smooth functions, and
$$
X = \phi \vec = \phi\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x},\qquad
Y = \psi \vec = \psi\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x}
$$
the associated vector fields.

Thinking of $\vec$ as a constant vector field (its value $(1, 0)$ is the same at every point), we have $\Del_{\vec} \vec = 0$. By ordinary calculus,
$$
\Del_{X}Y
  = \phi \frac{\dd}{\dd x}\biggl(\psi \frac{\dd}{\dd x}\biggr)
  = \phi \psi'\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x}.
\tag{1}
$$

The central point is that $\phi$, the component of $X$ (with respect to the frame $\vec$), appears in the right-hand expression via its *value*, while $\psi$, the component of $Y$, appears via the value of its *derivative*.

To highlight the distinction more clearly, let $f$ and $g$ be smooth functions. By (1),
$$
\Del_{fX}(gY) = (f\phi) (g\psi)'\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x}.
\tag{2}
$$
The factor $f$ in (2) is merely multiplied, and therefore factors out:
$$
\Del_{fX}(gY)
  = (f\phi) (g\psi)'\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x}
  = f\biggl(\phi (g\psi)'\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x}\biggr)
  = f \Del_{X}(gY).
$$
By contrast, the factor $g$ in (2) is *inside a derivative*, and consequently entails application of the product rule:
\begin{align*}
\Del_{fX}(gY)
  &= (f\phi) (g\psi)'\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x} \\
  &= (f\phi) (g\psi' + g'\psi)\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x} \\
  &= g(f\phi) \psi'\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x} + \bigl[(f\phi) g'\bigr] \psi)\, \frac{\dd}{\dd x} \\
  &= g\Del_{fX} Y + \bigl[(fX)g\bigr] Y.
\end{align*}

Conceptually, the point is that the vector fields $X$ and $Y$ in (1) do not play symmetric, interchangeable roles:

- The field $X$ acts as a *differential operator*. The value of $\Del_{X} Y$ at some point $p$ depends only on the value $X(p)$.
- The field $Y$ is the *object being differentiated*. The value of $\Del_{X} Y$ at some point $p$ depends on *derivatives* of the components of $Y$, i.e., on the values of $Y$ in a neighborhood of $p$.

Similar comments hold (for completely analogous reasons) on arbitrary manifolds, hence Do Carmo's axioms for an affine connection.

In case this distinction helps: The expression $\Del_{X} Y$ is *bilinear over scalars*: If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then
$$
\Del_{aX} (bY) = (ab) \Del_{X} Y.
$$
However, $\Del_{X} Y$ is *not bilinear over functions*, but only "linear in $X$". In the notation above,
$$
\Del_{fX} Y = f \Del_{X}Y,\qquad
\Del_{X} (gY)
  = \bigl[(\Del_{X})g\bigr]Y + g \Del_{X} Y
  = (Xg)Y + g \Del_{X} Y
$$

Comment: The value of the vector field $\mathbf{e}$ is actually "$1$", not "$(1, 0)$", but I'm leaving the "typo" for now in the hope that an ordered pair looks more "vector-like" than a real number. (The main computational and conceptual points of the answer stand.)

Comment: That was great. Makes lots of sense now. Follow up: why are these properties important for defining the notion of parallel transport on a manifold? They are used for that right?

Comment: Oh, well, to measure the discrepancy between an initial vector and a parallel transported vector, we need to be able to perform the basic rules of differentiation. This gives us that correct? Although I don't quite see why connecting tangent bundles with such a linear map helps with measuring that difference on the manifold itself (the difference meaning the one between initial vector and the parallel transported one)

Comment: @StanShunpike: "Why are these properties important"/"What are they used for" is a longish question for I don't have a short answer. :) (One can _say_ that "a connection gives a path-dependent means of comparing tangent spaces at different points of a Riemannian manifold", but justifying this philosophical claim in detail and giving concrete applications requires real work.)

Comment: Do you know of a book that does this? To my knowledge, do Carmo and John Lee's texts don't go into detail on that.

Comment: @StanShunpike, as I recall, Jost's Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis (section 4.1) has a short but useful discussion of the idea of "connecting tangent spaces" (or fibers of a more general vector bundle) with a connection.

Comment: @Stan: If memory serves, the first two volumes of Spivak's _Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry_ discuss which parts of multivariable calculus are independent of coordinate system (i.e., are part of "the theory of smooth manifolds") and which parts require additional structure (e.g., a Riemannian metric, or an affine connection).

Comment: It is by definition that $(\nabla_X)g=X(g)$ in the last line?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, the covariant derivative of a function by a vector field is the directional derivative (which depends only on the smooth structure).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, That is the point what confuses me. So beside by definition $\nabla$ is a map from $\mathcal{X}(M)\times\mathcal{X}(M)\to\mathcal{X}(M)$, one needs to extend $\nabla$ for general tensor field so that $\nabla_Xg$ would make sense?

Comment: @Jack: Briefly, "yes". I haven't checked standard treatments, but I believe it's standard to define $\nabla_{X} g = Xg$ for a smooth function $g$ as part of the definition of a connection (particularly when extending $\nabla$ to tensor fields other than vector fields).